# Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints when using UIImageView and UILabel inside a horizontal stackView programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode7

I have the following code

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
let kFontName = "SourceSansPro-Light"
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let firstRowTextLabel               = UILabel()
        firstRowTextLabel.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(self.view.frame.width).active = true
        firstRowTextLabel.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(20.0).active = true
        firstRowTextLabel.text  = "Hi World"
        firstRowTextLabel.font = UIFont(name:kFontName, size:24)
        // textLabel.textAlignment = .Center
        firstRowTextLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let firstRowImageView               = UIImageView()
        firstRowImageView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(60.0).active = true
        firstRowImageView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(60.0).active = true
        firstRowImageView.image = UIImage(named: "settings_black")
        firstRowImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let firstRowStackView   = UIStackView()
        firstRowStackView.axis  = UILayoutConstraintAxis.Horizontal
        firstRowStackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.FillEqually
        firstRowStackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.Center
        firstRowStackView.spacing = 25.0

        firstRowStackView.addArrangedSubview(firstRowImageView)
        firstRowStackView.addArrangedSubview(firstRowTextLabel)
        firstRowStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


        let secondRowLabel = UILabel()
        secondRowLabel.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(self.view.frame.width).active = true
        secondRowLabel.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(20.0).active = true


        let stackView   = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis  = UILayoutConstraintAxis.Vertical
        stackView.distribution  = UIStackViewDistribution.EqualSpacing
        stackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.Center
        stackView.spacing   = 25.0


        stackView.addArrangedSubview(firstRowStackView)
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.view.addSubview(stackView)


        stackView.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.centerXAnchor).active = true

        let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: stackView,
            attribute: .Top,
            relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: topLayoutGuide,
            attribute: .Bottom,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 50.0
        )
        self.view.addConstraint(constraint)
    }
...
}
```

When I run it, I get the following result :

[image: screenshots_horizontal_stackview_1]

This is the layout I am going for, except for the fact that I am getting the

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints

message in my console

When I comment out the following line :

```
firstRowStackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.FillEqually
```

the breaking constraints error in my console goes away but the layout does not have the image and text center aligned anymore and instead I get this :

[image: screenshots_horizontal_stackview_2]

What is the minimum change I need to the above code in order to achieve the following layout without breaking constraints :

[image: screenshots_horizontal_stackview_3]

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I just figured out the solution to this.

I changed the following line :

```
firstRowTextLabel.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(self.view.frame.width).active = true
```

to

```
firstRowTextLabel.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(100.0).active = true
```

and commented out the following line :

```
 // firstRowStackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.FillEqually
```

And that did the trick for me.